# Blogger | how to get comments number from feed

Tags: json, rss, blogger, feed

I just want to get the

> comments number, post text, thumbnail image

from one place

you can see the feed from this link

`https://tecnocode-temps-news.blogspot.com.eg/feeds/posts/default/-/فديوهات?alt=json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get comments JSON feed from this url

```
https://tecnocode-temps-news.blogspot.com.eg/feeds/comments/default?alt=json
```

To get comments number, you need to invoke JSON data from Javascript & callback like the following

```
<script>
    function comments(json) {
        var commentsNumber = json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t;
        document.write(commentsNumber + " comments");
    }
</script>
<script src="https://tecnocode-temps-news.blogspot.com.eg/feeds/comments/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=comments"></script>
```

Comment: Ok thank you
but do you know how to get the views number
or get the comments from the link I put in the post above
because I am making a slider an need all information in one callback function